# Change the sequence/order of solr facets in PLP - SAP commerce

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

We are using SAP hybris, have about 10 solr facets in the PLP.
I am trying to change the order of a new facet, currently it is displaying in the bottom, I gave it more priority to display it in the middle but my attempts went in vain.

I am changing the priority of the facet from backoffice and then performing full solr index, I am not able to take my facet one step above.
I thought the issue is with the new facet and tried to change the order of existing facets, but nothing worked.
Please find the impex below, i am changing the priority attribute.

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty; solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique = true]; name[unique = true]; type(code); sortableType(code); currency[default = false]; localized[default = false]; multiValue[default = false]; facet[default = true]; facetType(code); facetSort(code); priority; visible; useForSpellchecking[default = false]; useForAutocomplete[default = false]; fieldValueProvider            ; facetDisplayNameProvider; customFacetSortProvider; topValuesProvider; rangeSets(name)
                                 ; $solrIndexedType                          ; runFlat            ; string    ;                   ;                          ;                           ;                            ;                      ; MultiSelectOr  ; Alpha          ; 13      ; true   ;                                     ;                                    ;  ;                         ;                        ;                  ;
```

THanks in advance